# If $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{A_k}{x+k}=\frac{n!}{x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots(x+n)}$ Then find $A_7$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, permutations, binomial-coefficients

If $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{A_k}{x+k}=\frac{n!}{x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots(x+n)}$$ Then find $A_7$

My Try:

I have considered a function

$$f(x)=x^{A_0}(x+1)^{A_1}(x+2)^{A_2}\cdots(x+n)^{A_n}$$

taking natural log on both sides and then differentiating we get

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{A_k}{x+k}$$

hence

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{n!}{x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots(x+n)}$$

any clue here?

Comment: Please include additional context with your question, such as the source of the question, its motivation, any applications, etc.   It is good to include your work, but this does not indicate where the problem came from.

Answer (score 5):

Note that:

$$\frac1x\frac1{\binom{x+n}n}=\frac{n!}{x(x+1)(x+2)\dots(x+n)}$$

And thus,

$$\frac1x\left[\frac1{\binom{x+n}n}-\frac1{\binom{x+{n-1}}{n-1}}\right]=\frac{A_n}{x+n}$$

Which gives the general solution immediately.

Answer (score 2):

By using partial fractions, chance upon the solution $A_{0}=1,$ and $A_{1}=-1$. For $n>1$, in particular for all $n=7,$ it seems that

$$A_{7}=(x+7)(\frac{(7)!}{x(x+1)...(x+7)}-\frac{6!}{x(x+1)...(x+6)})
\\=6!\frac{7-(x+7)}{x(x+1)...(x+6)}=6!\frac{-x}{x(x+1)...(x+6)}
\\=-\frac{6!}{(x+1)...(x+6)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $x+7$ and for $x = -7$ you have $A_7 = -\frac{n!}{7!(n-7)!}$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{x(x+1)}&=&\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1} \\
\frac{2}{x(x+1)(x+2)}&=&\frac{1}{x(x+1)}-\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x+2} \\
\frac{6}{x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}&=&\frac{2}{x(x+1)(x+2)}-\frac{2}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}\\&=&\frac{1}{x}-\frac{3}{x+1}+\frac{3}{x+2}- \frac{1}{x+3}\\
\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
$A_7= \color{red}{\binom{n}{7}}$.